# QGIS: Flow Accumulation Tool not progressing past 100%

Tags: qgis, saga, hydrology, flow-accumulation, loading

I'm trying to do run the flow accumulation tool on a map where I am trying to extract drainage from a DEM however it has been stuck at 100% for several hours. I have put details of the files I am using at the bottom.

For the context of what I had been doing before, I had downloaded a DEM of some tiles of a region of island coastline. I then used the Fill Basin tool to create the filled basin layers, flow direction layers, and watershed basin layer. For the flow accumulation I had tried to use the flow direction layer created however have not been able to make any progress at all.

It has been stuck at 100% for ~3 hours now and I am slightly worried that my laptop does not have the processing power to complete it as there are further applications I need to do which is not viable in terms of time if it is taking this long for each tool use and is using 100% of my CPU. I had tried with no other application running but it still did not make a difference.

Any advice?

Data Type:Float32
File Size: 132.47 MB

Comment: 132Mb is a tiny raster. You should not wait forever for this to finish. Killing the job and retrying is an option, as is converting the float to an integer cost surface.

Comment: Try installing Whitebox Tools - it has some flow accumulation tools that are fast.